# Encoding a tuple or dict in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, byte

I'm using the cryptography module to encrypt some data and then trying to store it in my SQL datbase. When it is a string, it works. However, when I'm trying to use a tuple or a dict it fails. I have the following as my function that is being called. (uses crypytography.Fernet.encrypt).

```
def encrypt(to_encrypt):
    ''' Takes a bytestring and returns a token. '''
    key = get_key()
    f = make_fernet_object(key)
    token = f.encrypt(to_encrypt)
    return token
```

If I try to pass a tuple or dict to it directly, I get

> TypeError: data must be bytes.

If I use

```
bytes(my_tuple)
```

Then I get

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

How do I turn my tuple (which contains 2 strings and a dict) into a bytes object that Fernet will encrypt so I can put the blob in my SQL database?

edit - The tuple in question is in the format..

```
my_tuple = ('username', 'password', {'memorable question':'memorable answer', 'memorable question 2', 'memorable answer 2'})
```

Comment: You have to `encode()` strings to be able to convert to bytes, e.g. you could `bytes(str(my_tuple).encode('utf-8'))` but hard to tell if this would meet your requirements.

Comment: @AChampion `str(my_tuple)` will produce the string representation of a tuple literal, probably not what OP has in mind. (I'm assuming only the content of the tuple matters.)

Comment: Very possibly, unclear what the OP wants - he mentioned a `blob` so wondered if he wants to recover the tuple later, perhaps should have used `repr()`.

Comment: Did you consider `pickle` so serialize the object?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Ultimately I'm trying to store the contents of a tuple (defined in the answer) in a database, and then be able to retrieve it later to access its individual parts.
I'm not stuck on a tuple, a list would be fine. I just figured I was meant to use tuple as the contents will never change.

`str(my_tuple)` works but then I've got to do string manipulation afterwards to retrieve the individual parts. That's easy enough for the username + password but harder for the dict.

Comment: I've just tried @AChampion idea of `repr()` - my first time using it, and reversing it with `eval()` seems to work although I find articles that say it's a bad idea.
I've never used `pickle` but will look at that as an alternative. Thank you.

Comment: `import ast; ast.literal_eval(repr(my_tuple))` is considered safe and maybe sufficient.

Comment: `pickled = pickle.dumps(to_encrypt)`
and
`depickled = pickle.loads(decrypted_pickle)`

Work perfectly. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

As your error messages say, `encrypt` only accepts bytes as input. You can format a string as bytes, but not a tuple, which is a sequence of python objects. You can pass either of the two strings contained within the tuple to `bytes()`, or delimit and concatenate them as a single string and pass it, but you cannot pass the tuple itself (without specifying a method of converting it to a string and recovering said string as a tuple).

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/fernet/

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that your data is strongly typed
like `tuple[str, str, dict[str, str]]`

In that case, this might help (if it isn't, maybe it can help, but it is harder)
I defined a class that can serialize iterable of bytes (I'll put it on the bottom)
It simply (de)serializes multiple things, you just need to tell it what to serialize
you could then use it in your case like

```py
obj = my_tuple = ('username', 'password', {'memorable question':'memorable answer', 'memorable question 2': 'memorable answer 2'})
serialized = ArgsToBytes.argsToBytes(serializeStr(obj[0]), serializeStr(obj[1]), ArgsToBytes.argsToBytes(*(ArgsToBytes.argsToBytes(serializeStr(k), serializeStr(v)) for (k, v) in obj[2].items())))
# serialized == b'8:username8:password96:42:18:memorable question16:memorable answer0:46:20:memorable question 218:memorable answer 20:0:0:'
a = ArgsToBytes.bytesToArgs(serialized)
# a == [b'username', b'password', b'42:18:memorable question16:memorable answer0:46:20:memorable question 218:memorable answer 20:0:']
b = ArgsToBytes.bytesToArgs(a[2])
# b == [b'18:memorable question16:memorable answer0:', b'20:memorable question 218:memorable answer 20:']
c = dict(ArgsToBytes.bytesToArgs(x) for x in b)
#c == {b'memorable question': b'memorable answer', b'memorable question 2': b'memorable answer 2'}
```

As you can see, it is quite a bit to write here
Ideally, you would separate things to classes and functions

```py
class ArgsToBytes:
    @staticmethod
    def argsToBytes(*args) -> bytes:
        serialized = b"";
        for arg in args:
            if not isinstance(arg, bytes): arg = bytes(arg);
            length = len(arg);
            serialized += str(length).encode("ascii") + b":" + arg;
        pass
        serialized += b":";
        return serialized;
    pass
    @staticmethod
    def bytesToArgs(serialized: bytes) -> list:
        result = [];
        i = 0;
        while True:
            index = serialized.index(b":", i);
            if index == i: break;
            length = serialized[i : index];
            i = index + 1;
            length = int(length.decode("ascii"));
            index = i + length;
            result.append(serialized[i : index]);
            i = index;
        pass
        return result;
    pass
pass
```